# Dúvida Migração de sistema cliente-servidor, FireDac para mais de 1 banco de dados?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Um sistema foi desenvolvido usando Firebird é dbexpress, para migração deste sistema de forma que fosse possível utilizar mais de 1 banco de dados, qual seria a melhor solução?
No Delphi XE temos o FireDac com acesso a vários bancos de dados, mais quando se utiliza (SQLQuery + DataSetProvider + ClientDataSet) os campos é tipos de campos da tabela em questão são carregados, mais estes tipos não são iguais para ambos os bancos, neste caso será que o FireDac consegue tratar os tipos de dados dentro dele ou existiria alguma outra forma de fazer?
Agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Sim, o FireDac consegue fazer isso. Passamos pela mesma situação, porem no meu caso, decidiu-se usar os componentes da DevArt.
Sugiro que primeiramente, você crie componentes customizados de conexão, para que possa tratar as diferenças entre os bancos.

Por exemplo:

FireBird:

> Select first 1 ID from Table

PostgreSQL:

> Select ID from Table Limit 1

Essas e outras diferenças, poderiam ser tratadas no seu componente customizado.

Quanto ao tipo do campo na tabela, acredito que a maioria deles seriam os mesmos, exceto pelos tipo Blob em Firebird, onde costumamos usar o Bytea/Text em PostgreSQL

Sugiro também, que você monte o comando SQL em tempo de execução, assim você aproveita o Drive e ele mesmo trás o tipo certo do Field, alem de garantir que os Fields estarão sempre atualizado, sem ter que prestar manutenção no código fonte.